# Ripples in passband of chebeshev filter

Tags: chebyshev-filters

I am studying filters and I am not able to find a reason why ripples appear in the passband of chebeshev filter. I know it has a high roll off and the ripples are due to high order but In Butterworth and Bessel high order filters we don't have ripples in their passband so where does those ripples come in the pass band of chebeshev filter and also in inverse chebeshev filter how can there be ripples in the stop band when the filter should have attenuated the signal completely. I would really appreciate a less mathematical and a more conceptual answer